# Changing the dtype of category codes in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, casting, dtype

Let's say I have a boolean column stored as a `category` in a `pandas.DataFrame`. But there's a twist - the underlying values are `str`, not `bool`. I.e., the values are `"True"`/`"False"`, not `True`/`False`.

How do I:

1. change the dtype of the underlying category values (e.g. from `"True"` to `True`) **and**
2. continue storing the field as a `category`?

Having the boolean values as strings is an issue with `DataFrame.query`, for example. I have to specify `DataFrame.query("field == 'True'")`, which is pretty horrendous lol.

FYI - I don't want to do `DataFrame.astype(dict(field=bool))`, because then i lose the memory efficiency from `category`. i want to keep the category dtype.

Comment: you want to change the dtype only when applying the query ? Im not sure I understand what you want to do with that column exactly

Comment: i just mention `query` as an example of why i want to change the dtype of the underlying category value. does that make sense?

Comment: What memory efficiency are you referring to? Bools use less memory than Category. Category fo course are stored as ints, but also need a hash map etc.

Comment: Very good point about bools being more memory efficient than categories.  I also have numbers stored as strings, though, which I'd also like to type-cast (and still store as categories)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can try:

```
df['field'] = df['field'].replace({'True': True, 'False': False})
print(df['field'])

# Output
0    False
1     True
2     True
3    False
Name: field, dtype: category
Categories (2, object): [False, True]  # <- bool
```

With `query`:

```
>>> df.query('field == True')
  field
1  True
2  True
```

Setup:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'field': ['False', 'True', 'True', 'False']}, dtype='category')
print(df['field'])

# Output
0    False
1     True
2     True
3    False
Name: field, dtype: category
Categories (2, object): ['False', 'True']  # <- str
```

Comment: I do not know which version you are using but the moment you replace it turns the whole column to a boolean type. Also what does OP mean with memory efficient? Categories use more memory than bools in storage

Comment: I use `Pandas==1.4.1`

Comment: lol, OP here - yes i know bools are more mem efficient than categories. i have other categories that i'd like to typecast from string to other things as well. just gave a silly example. point being - i simply want to change the dtype of the underlying category values.

Comment: this answer seems great! as a slight improvement (less text), it looks like one can also do: `df = df.replace({"field": {"True": True, "False": False}})`. and indeed `df["field"].dtype` is still `category`. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you could try to do that (the values can be used as bools but are mentionned as categories in the data type):

```
import pandas as pd

# before
data = ['True', 'False', 'True']
df = pd.DataFrame({'data': data}).astype("category")

print('[BEFORE] \n data type = {0} \n values : {1}'.format(df['data'].dtypes, df.values))

# after
df['data'] = list(map(bool, list(df['data'].values)))
df = df.astype("category")

print('[AFTER] \n data type = {0} \n values : {1}'.format(df['data'].dtypes, df.values))
```

output:

```
[BEFORE] 
 data type = category
 values : [['True']
 ['False']
 ['True']]
[AFTER]
 data type = category
 values : [[True]
 [True]
 [True]]
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but this has too many type casts. i dont want to convert to something, and then convert back to category. that said, again, thank you for this answer :)

Comment: I guess  this does not work as expected since `bool("False") is True` - see the output above.